# OSGI bundle activated, but component never created when using DS and Apache Karaf

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I am working on a Hello World application. My application is built with Maven (3.5.0), uses Apache Felix annotations, and is run in Apache Karaf (4.1.1). My application consists of a single component, called App, that should be started immediately. The bundle builds successfully. I can successfully install it into Karaf from my mvn repository. Karaf shows the bundle as "Active". The problem is that constructor and the activate method of my component (App) are never invoked. I need a second set of eyes to help me figure out why this happens. What am I missing in my pom.xml?

For completeness, I created an Activator class in my project that implements BundleActivator. I then instructed Maven to set my Bundle-Activator to this new class. Now, when I install my bundle in Karaf, I can see the log output from my Activator. The start method is being hit. So I know my bundle is actually starting. I just don't understand why my App component is never created and activated.

Here are the relevant files.

**App.java**

```
package myCompany;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;

@Component(immediate=true)
public class App 
{
    public App()
    {
        System.out.println( "App constructed" );
    }

    @Activate
    public void activate()
    {
        System.out.println( "App activated" );
    }
}
```

**Activator.java**

```
package myCompany;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator  implements BundleActivator{

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Activator started");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Activator stopped");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myProject</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.24.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <_dsannotations>*</_dsannotations>
                        <_metatypeannotations>*</_metatypeannotations>
                        <Bundle-Activator>myCompany.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karaf does not include support for declarative services out of the box. You need to install the scr feature to activate DS support:

```
feature:install scr
```

Comment: That worked. With my bundle already loaded in Karaf (but not doing anything) I ran feature:install scr, and voila, I finally see my "App constructed" and "App activated" messages pop up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using obsolete annotations from the `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations` package, which are not recognised or processed by bnd — they require an additional Maven plugin to work.

It would be better to migrate your code to use the OSGi standard annotations from the `org.osgi.service.component.annotations` package. See OSGi Compendium Release 6 specification, section 112.8.

Comment: Christian Schneider provided my immediate solution below. I actually did start with standard OSGI annotations but was having trouble getting my bundle generated correctly so I switched to what I know well, Felix SCR annotations. Now that I have Felix SCR annotations working, I will revisit the standard OSGI annotations.